# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't recognize color profiles

Tags: display, 17.10, color-management

After installing 17.10 I got a warning that my custom color profile could not be loaded. I tried installing the color profile again using DisplayCAL but that didn't seem to have an effect. My custom color profile is not shown in Settings -> Color. That dialogue changed quite a bit, and I don't see how to install additional profiles from there.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install the profile again using `colormgr`. I found the device with

```
colormgr get-devices
```

and the profile with

```
colormgr get-profiles
```

(I guess DisplayCal had registered it there).
Then I could add it with

```
colormgr device-add-profile <DEVICE> <PROFILE>
```

That made it show up in the Settings->color dialogue.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. But the command `colormgr get-profiles` does not show the profile created by DisplayCAL.
Also, `colormgr import-profile /path/to/cal.icc` does not work. 
The resources on this topic are very scarce. Do you have an idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a restart solved the problem for me. After the restart, the profile is shown in the list in Settings -> Color